# Missing value ("is_coach_recommended") in API Khan response

Tags: khan-academy

I found that currently the API call corresponding to "`/api/v1/user/exercises`" doesn't return the value "`is_coach_recommended`".  That says if the corresponding exercise (skill) was recommended or not by the teacher; this in contrast to the example json response example presented in the API explorer (http://api-explorer.khanacademy.org/api/v1/user/exercises) where it does appear.

Do you know how to make it appear? Maybe using a request that queries a previous version of API Khan? That information is critically important for the development of our project so I hope you can help me to make that information back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be documented. Usually an attribute like this would be present with a value of true or false, or it would not be present. And there should be rules describing how you should interpret "not present".

"Should be documented" rarely means it *is* documented. You might have a look at some data; if out of 1,000 records 500 have a value "true", 500 have no value, and none have a value "false", then clearly "not present" means "false". If you have 400 true, 400 false, 200 not present, then "not present" might mean "not known".